# Android use Parcelable to send data between activities

Tags: android, android-intent, arraylist, parcelable

In my application I want to pass an `ArrayList` of `Parcelable` objects (or a `Parcelable[]`) between two activities. On the first activity i call a restservice to get the json data, after that I use gson to get the `List` of `Parcelable` object and then i send the list to the second activity using `putParcelableArrayListExtra(...)`. All works fine until the size of the list is about 1000, but over this size I get an ANR and application won't resume even if I wait for some minutes.

Is there a solution for this issue maintaining this approach? Is it due to a size limit for object put to an Intent?

I know I could pass the Json String and then get the list on the second activity, but I prefer to make first this kind of operations.

Answer (score 0):

First off, ensure that the *source* of your ANR is indeed the large parcelable object, and not because you were performing a blocking operation (i.e. networking) on the main thread.

Now if the ANR issue really is due to these large objects, the *right* way to get this done is to deserialize the object and write it out to storage *instead* of passing it between activities. You're effectively doubling the amount of memory you incur by doing what you're doing.

Here are a few ways you can troubleshoot this:

- [StrictMode:](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.html) StrictMode is most commonly used to catch accidental disk or network access on the application's main thread, where UI operations are received and animations take place. By keeping your application's main thread responsive, you also prevent ANR dialogs from being shown to users.
- [Traceview:](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html#tracewiew) Traceview is a graphical viewer to see logs created by an Android application. Via Traceview you can find errors in your application and measure its performance.
- [Memory Dump:](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseMemoryAnalyser/article.html) You can create a memory snapshot and analyse it with the Eclipse Memory Analyzer.

Comment: I'm sure the ANR is due to the large parcelable because the network request is done into a AsyncTask and after retreiving result I put the result in the Intent and start the new activity, which will not show up...

Comment: @danidif Then if that's the case, you'll have to troubleshoot to see what exactly is happening (using StrictMode, Traceview, etc). I suspect you're running out of memory which is why I suggested deserializing (and writing it to storage) instead of passing it around.

Comment: It tried also to pass the entire json strig to the Intent and to get the objects using gson on the second activity and the resul is: JAVA FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION...